# Unable to find element when html document is inside an iframe

Tags: c#, html, selenium, iframe, ui-automation

```
<div class="reporting-graph-zone">
    <input id="ctl00_m_g_a3080099_ed02_44e3_afe2_e6b89d1a2cee_ctl00_hiCulture" name="ctl00$m$g_a3080099_ed02_44e3_afe2_e6b89d1a2cee$ctl00$hiCulture" value="culture=en-US" type="hidden">
    <iframe src="/PL/__LI_Partners/FederationMetadata/WIF.axd?ReturnUrl=%2frdPage.aspx%3frdReport%3dSingleDashboard%26culture%3den-US" style="">
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html id="yui_3_1_1487760521746_220" class="yui3-js-enabled" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:rdxslextension="urn:rdXslExtension" style="cursor: auto;">
                <head>
                <body id="yui_3_1_1487760521746_219" onload="rdBodyLoad()">
                    <div id="yui_3_1_1487760521746_369" class="yui3-widget rdquicktip yui3-widget-positioned rdquicktip-hidden" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                    <form id="yui_3_1_1487760521746_218" name="rdForm" method="POST">
                        <table id="rdRows-1" class="rdDashboardPanelContainer" style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody id="yui_3_1_1487760521746_215">,
                            <tr id="rdDashboardMenu">
```

I am unable to find element **"rdDashboardMenu"** when html document is inside an iframe.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You should first select frame using below code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

After switching frame select element

Comment: Still unable to find the elements. I am able to switch to the iframe but unable to find element present inside the html document.